# Angular 2 ngModel can't track/bind the value in jQuery Datepicker widget/Input element, why?

Tags: angular, jquery-ui-datepicker, angular2-ngmodel

This input element is a Datepicker Widget. The date property value e.g., "09/09/1999" is loaded to template view, and in Datepicker calender the same date is selected, works as expected. The binding from component to template is ok.

But when I change date in Datepicker interactive calender, selected date is displayed in the input box, but date property in component is not updated. And when I use (ngSubmit)='search(form.value)', form object form.date value is same as before.

```
--template---    
<form #form='ngForm' (ngSubmit)='search(form.value)'>    
<input type="text" id="datepicker" [(ngModel)]="date" name="date">    
<button type="submit"> click </button>
</form>

--component---
export class AppComponent {    
    public date = "09/09/1999";    
    search(form: any) {
        console.log("date:" + form.date);   // date: 
    }    
}
```

Yes, I can use local template variable #date to pass the input value to component, like this (ngSubmit)="search(date.value)". But for multiple input Datepicker, I can concatenate the local variables value and pass it parameter to search().

I want to know why ngModel can not track the change in datepicker input and what is the possible best way to update the component property or form.value ?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery with Angular? jQuery is such a headache - it wraps native DOM objects in a custom wrapper which causes nightmares for JS frameworks such as Angular. If you need a datepicker you can use one of many ng libraries out there. ngx-bootstrap to name one.

Comment: I am using jQuery because my expected datepicker ui features and styles are available very much in jQuery datepicker, but not in other angular datepickers e.g. ngx-bootstrap. And I am not yet skilled enough to understand how jQuery and JS framework like angular make things complected. But do you have any suggestion to solve it if I still want to use jQuery, or explanation why ngModel can't read datepicker input value. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot advise you in getting jQuery datepicker to work with Angular - as It would require major re-writes of core jQuery or core Angular.

For an explanation as to why ngModel cannot read jQuery-UI Objects have a [look at this post I made earlier on a similar thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43760964/5645292)

ngModel relies on access to native DOM objects - jQuery abstracts these objects into its own custom jQuery object. Angular does not have an API for dealing with this jQuery object.