# JQuery date pickers in Angular

Tags: angular, jquery-ui

I have a jqueryUI date picker used in an Angular application. The date picker has an ng-change event assigned to it. This fires off OK when the user enters a date with the keyboard directly in the textbox but fails to execute when the popup dialog for the date is used. Does anybody know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised to use jQuery with Angular (or even at all nowadays) - the reason you are experiencing weird behaviour is because jQuery wraps Native DOM objects like NodeList etc. in a custom jQuery object.

> So, what is returned when you run $("div") is not a reference to an
> element, or a NodeList, it’s a jQuery object. This means that a jQuery
> object has completely different methods available to it than a
> reference to a DOM element, an array with elements or any type of
> NodeList. However, these native objects come up all the time in real
> code — as much as jQuery tries to abstract them away, you always have
> to deal with them, even if it’s just wrapping them in $().

As you might expect - directives like ngIf, ngModel and other fundamental Angular directives rely *heavily on native DOM* objects.

**So what does this mean for jQuery + Angular?**

Well if Angular is looking for a **HTMLInputElement** but it finds a completely different object wrapped - **$("input")** which contains many *strange methods* for which Angular has no API - you are going to get erroneous behavior to say the least.

There are many *better* alternatives out there when it comes to pre-built components.

[ngx-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap)

[primeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/)

[material2](https://github.com/angular/material2)

### [Check out this article on why jQuery is harmful](http://lea.verou.me/2015/04/jquery-considered-harmful/)